# Group Many List In Two's

Tags: python

I currently have a list with one element inside each. Is there a way python can combine the first two lists into one? I tried my code down below. The last for loop Is my attempt. If you see the actual output, it only duplicates it but doesnt get the second element. I need the first and second element to be listed together. Please note that the post i made earlier is not a duplicate of the post mentioned there. The post the moderator had suggested is answwering a question on how to split a SINGLE list into even chunks. I am asking how to group together many lists in 2's. Basically what i am doing is opening a file, looking for value between the strings 'cdc or dcc\s(space)' and returning those values. I  then want to compare it to the string that comes next.

text.txt

```
   ^random binary characters  d1234 d0123456789d 1234c null null null d34 dc49416494949 c3456
```

output:

```
['d1234d0123456789d1234c']
['d34dc49416494949c3456']
```

expected output:

```
['d1234d0123456789d1234c','d34dc49416494949c3456']
```

code:

```
    with open(text.txt, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as in_file:
        data = in_file.readlines()
        for row in data:
                micr_ocr_line = re.findall(r'd[^d]*d[^d]*c[0-9]+|d[^d]*d[^d]*c\s+[0-9]+', row)
                for r in micr_ocr_line:
                    rmve_spcl_char = re.sub (r'([^a-zA-Z-0-9]+?)', '', r)
                    rmve_spcl_char = re.sub(r'(c\d{4,}).*', r'\1', rmve_spcl_char)
                    a = [l for l in rmve_spcl_char.split('\n')]
                     for previous, current in zip_longest(a, a[::1]):
                        print(previous, current)
                        micr_ocr_dat = [previous, current]
                        print(micr_ocr_dat)
                        micr_ocr_dat_l.append(micr_ocr_dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it I think - just slice slightly different?

```py
a = [l for l in rmve_spcl_char.split('\n')]
for previous, current in zip(a[::2], a[1::2]):
    print(previous, current)
    micr_ocr_dat = [previous, current]
    print(micr_ocr_dat)
    micr_ocr_dat_l.append(micr_ocr_dat)
```

Comment: I dont get any results printed that way. If i use zip_longest(a, a[::1]) then i get duplicate['d1234d0123456789d1234c','d1234d0123456789d1234c'] instead of the first and second elements together like : ['d1234d0123456789d1234c','d34dc49416494949c3456']

Answer (score 0):

btw , you should use len to get the length of the list and use range() to the for loop
Here is the way to split it in two

```
for fp in dat_filepath:
        with open(fp, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as in_file:
        data = in_file.readlines()
        listresult = []
        for a in range(0, len(data), 2):
            listresult.append([data[a], data[a + 1]])
        print(listresult)
```

The list result shuld be the data you expected